# How to loop through two data sets and pull key values in JS

Tags: javascript, loops

I've got two data sets: transactions and categories(budgets).

I'm trying to show a progress bar from on side of the parent element to the other with the width based on what % of my budget for X category I've spent. So far I'm stumped on how to loop through one data set inside of another one.

Any help?

Here's my codepen http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/wWdGoB?editors=0010

```
var data_transactions = [
 {category_name: "Utilities", category_id: "1", name: "Seattle City Light", amount: "232.03"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "TacoBell", amount: "26.38"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "Wendys", amount: "13.23"}, 
 {category_name: "Groceries", category_id: "2", name: "Walmart", amount: "26.38"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "TacoBell", amount: "26.38"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "Wendys", amount: "13.23"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "TacoBell", amount: "26.38"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "Wendys", amount: "13.23"}, 
 {category_name: "Groceries", category_id: "2", name: "Walmart", amount: "26.38"}, 
 {category_name: "Utilities", category_id: "1", name: "Seattle City Light", amount: "100.00"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "TacoBell", amount: "26.38"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", name: "Wendys", amount: "13.23"}, 
 {category_name: "Groceries", category_id: "2", name: "Walmart", amount: "1226.38"},
 {category_name: "Groceries", category_id: "2", name: "Target", amount: "34.39"}
];

var data_categories = [
 {category_name: "Utilities", category_id: "1", totalBudget: "300.00"}, 
 {category_name: "Food", category_id: "3", totalBudget: "500.00"}, 
 {category_name: "Groceries", category_id: "2", totalBudget: "1500.00"}, 
];

var totals = data_transactions.reduce(function(c,x){
    if(!c[x.category_id]) c[x.category_id] = {
        category_name: x.category_name,
        total_amount: 0
    };
    c[x.category_id].total_amount += Number(x.amount);
    return c;
}, {});

var text = '';
var output = '';
var totalBudgetForAll = '2500.00';

for(var i in totals){
    // here's where I'm lost. How to loop through data_categories, get the related category and it's total then make into a variable. The next line of code is making the bar based on the categorie's spending in relatship to the budgetForAll instead of the category itself.
    totalProgress = totals[i].total_amount / totalBudgetForAll * 100;
    output += "<p>" + totals[i].category_name + ': $' + totals[i].total_amount.toFixed(0) + "</p><div class='ProgressBar' style='width:" + totalProgress + "%'></div>";    
}

$('#output').html(output);
```

Comment: Looks like it's working to me? What's the problem?

Comment: You're looking for the percentage in respect to each categories `totalBudget` instead of the `totalBudgetForAll`?

Comment: Something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbPymd?editors=0010)?

Comment: Are you trying something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKmKNO)